# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 75: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python

desde un tiempo he estado intentando ejecutar el programa pero me sale este error:

```
  File "C:\Users\"Usuario"\Downloads\files\dds.py", line 2, in <module>
    r = map_file.read()
  File "C:\Users\"Usuario"\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 75: character maps to <undefined>
```

el codigo que utilice fue este

```
map_file = open("map.wbox")
r = map_file.read()
e = zlib.decompress(r)
map_json = e.decode("utf8")
```

Comment: existe un caracter que no puede ser decodificado, tal vez porque esta en otra codificación o te has equivocado de codificación

Comment: Estuve buscando tutoriales sobre el modulo zlib para entender como funciona. En tu código abres el archivo en modo lectura normal. Esto intenta leer el archivo como si fuera texto plano. Pero [en el tutorial que encontré](https://stackabuse.com/python-zlib-library-tutorial) abren los archivos en modo "rb", o sea lo leen en forma de bytes. Teniendo esto en cuenta, probaste con cambiar esto `open("map.wbox")` por esto `open("map.wbox", "rb")`?